# Transferring Files to AWS from Server using Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a easy way of transferring all files in a server to AWS S3 without downloading them and re-uploading them to the server? I have about 200k files I need to transfer to my S3 bucket. They're very small in size (10kb) but I imagine this is going to bog down the sever with timeouts or errors.

```
$images = Image::all();

foreach($images as $image)
{
 $aws = Storage::disk('s3');
 $aws->put('/images/', file_get_contents($image->path), 'public');
}
```

Is this the only way I can do this? Is it possible to upload all files from a zip? Server is on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done using AWS CLI and S3 either `cp`or `sync` command.

Here is the installation guide for AWS CLI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

And S3sync command reference 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html